# Is it possible to use procmon to find out why a process ends?

Tags: windows, sysinternals, process-monitor, procmon

Let's say I started notepad. In a PowerShell window, I run `ps notepad | Stop-Process -Force` to kill all notepad session. I captured a procmon trace during these operations. Is it possible to find out it's the PowerShell that caused notepad to exit? I tried, but I failed. All the entries are success and there seems no clue for that. I just want to know if this is even possible. Thanks.

Comment: Procmon is not going to show you what took place inside the exe when it got the exit message.  The message itself came from the kernel and because it was a windowed application, it recieved a [WM_QUIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-quit) message in it's message queue and the application did what it was told.   In the case of notepad, technically, you could watch the window messages using spy++ and see this behavior but I don't understand the point of this exercise.  You have me intrigued.  Perhaps someone has better info.

Comment: This is a simplified scenario of my actual problem. I have installed an application. When I start it, it runs, and I can even see its splash windows. But after that, it exits immediately. I suspect it's one of the program on my computer killed it, but I don't have proof.

Comment: You might be able to create the right filters within procmon to see this behavior by watching what took place when.  If you know how to use a proper debugger, you might also be able to debug when the WM_QUIT message comes in a debug the stack.  This will be difficult but do-able.

Comment: The common way is to install the software in a clean environment, e.g. a new Windows VM. Then you will see if it works or not. Or you use you current Windows and step-by-step close all applications and disable all services.

Comment: @Robert It's not possible in my case. The software is a commercial one, and it's heavily tested on all supported OSs. The issue only happened on my laptop. I'm sure it will work in clean VMs.